# How to get inner text from span which include other hidden span?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have some test html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page for test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="r_tr">
        <span class="r_rs">Inner text<span class="otherSpan" style="display: none">text</span></span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get "Inner text".
I am using HtmlAgilityPack.
I write this method

```
public string GetInnerTextFromSpan(HtmlDocument doc)
{
    const string rowXPath = "//*[@class=\"r_tr\"]";
    const string spanXPath = "//*[@class=\"r_rs\"]";
    string text = null;
    HtmlNodeCollection rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(rowXPath);
    foreach(HtmlNode row in rows)
    {
        text = row.SelectSingleNode(spanXPath).InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine("textL {0}", text);
    }
    return text;

}
```

but this method return "Inner texttext".
I write some unit test for explain my problem

```
[Test]
public void TestGetInnerTextFromSpan()
{
    var client = new PromtTranslatorClient();
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"testPage.html");
    var text = client.GetInnerTextFromSpan(doc);
    StringAssert.AreEqualIgnoringCase("Inner text", text);
}
```

and result

```
Expected string length 10 but was 14. Strings differ at index 10.
  Expected: "Inner text", ignoring case
  But was:  "Inner texttext"
  ---------------------^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know XPath but here is solution using LINQ:

```
String inner = (from x in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                where x.Name == "span"
                && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "r_rs"
                select 
                      (from y in x.ChildNodes
                       where y.Name == "#text"
                       select y.InnerText).FirstOrDefault()
                ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your `spanXPath` is incorrect. `//` at the start means "start from the root", so `row.SelectSingleNode(spanXPath)` will always give the first element with class `r_rs` in the document, not in the row. Drop the `//` to fix this.

Then, `text()` is the XPath for a text node. You can use

```
var span = row.SelectSingleNode(spanXPath);
var textNode = span.SelectSingleNode("text()");
text = textNode.InnerText;
Console.WriteLine("textL {0}", text);
```

in your `foreach` loop to get the first text node in the selected span.

Comment: It turns out you were selecting the first `r_rs` element in the entire document, and I was selecting the first text node in the entire document - I've udpated my answer to fix this.